# NSPACE(n^2) and DSPACE(n^2) class problems

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

What problems belong in NSPACE(n^2) and DSPACE(n^2) class? Examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty problem $\emptyset$ (the problem whose answer is always *false*) is in both $\mathsf{NSPACE}(n^2)$ and $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n^2)$.

(If you are unsatisfied with this answer, then you should be more precise in your question).